# Google Drive asks to sign in for download after security update

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been hosting PDF documents for my web page on Google Drive for a couple of years (enabling "Anyone with the link can view" and copying the link).

Google recently started rolling out a [security update](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743?p=update_drives_user) to files on Google Drive.
For files that have had the security update applied, I now have the following issue:

When opening the link to the file (from "Get link") in incognito mode, I do get a preview of the PDF as usual but when clicking on the Download button [image], I am asked to log into my Google account.

Example link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7lz1BqbSo58aHY4X004VDNObDA/view?resourcekey=0-nkoC7Sk1isZb0Hpffo3vQg

This is not the case for files where the security update has not yet been applied (with old-style links of the form https://drive.google.com/open?id=1... ) or for files where I [removed the security update again](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743?p=update_drives_user).

Example link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7lz1BqbSo58NDZWUWoxbjNocHc/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-J8yGfrjL6vrO-olYxFmLfg

With the new security update applied, is there a way for users to download the file without having to log in?

Comment: Not able to reproduce; both links (a CV and a PDF with some data) could be downloaded without logging into google account (Brave Incognito).

Comment: Apologies @Carlo, my fault - I started removing the security update from the files linked from my web site and forgot that one of them was linked here as an example. I've now re-applied the security update to the first link.

Comment: To me, it seems to be working while the `resourcekey` is in the link. If I remove it, then it asks to log in (I'm guessing to check if you have an account which this file is shared with). Is this not what you're observing?

Comment: Thanks for checking @Martí - did you use "incognito mode", i.e. are you sure you were not logged into some Google account? When I open the first link in Chrome incognito mode, I am still redirected to log in when I click on the download button.

Comment: @leopold.talirz Yeah, I used Chrome's incognito mode. Both example links work for me. I'd try doing 2 things: Force to reload the page with Ctrl+Shift+R, and to close all isntances of chrome and opening them again (just in case). Also, make sure that the link contains the `resourcekey`.

Comment: @Martí that's weird - I can still reproduce the issue, both in Chrome incognito and in the Brave browser (where I'm not logged in). Again, this is just to make sure we're doing exactly the same thing: the login prompt appears only after clicking the "Download" button; opening the link always works fine (unless you remove the `resourcekey`).

Comment: Screen recording: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCsR.gif

Comment: I misread your question. I can reproduce this. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a nice [writeup on Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/07/heres-what-that-google-drive-security-update-message-means/) explains the reasons behind the security update: in 2017, Google updated the generation of links in order to make them harder to guess.
The purpose of the security update is to prevent unwanted access to links generated before that date.

It seems to me that the request for authentication when clicking on the download button may be a bug (at least it does not serve any obvious security purpose).

However, in the use case mentioned in the question, there is anyhow no need to keep the link secret as it is posted publicly on the web. It is therefore safe to manually remove the security update from the file(s) in question.

New files are not affected by this issue as the generated links are considered safe without a `resourcekey` (I checked).

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is that the download button goes to the download link without the `resourcekey` added into it. This is most likely a bug. To report it go to one of the files, and click the 3 vertical dots on the top right > `Send feedback`. Explain this behavior there. You can also add the screenshot and highlight the download button.

Comment: Thanks @Martí, will do that.

Comment: Upvoted your answer - I will still accept mine since I think it provides the answer to the original question.